# NHibernate HQL's Equivalent to T-SQL's TOP Keyword

Tags: .net, nhibernate, orm, hql

What is NHibernate HQL's Equivalent to T-SQL's TOP Keyword?

Also what is the non-HQL way for saying give me the first 15 of a class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy in HQL:

```
var top15 = session.CreateQuery("from SomeEntity")
                .SetFirstResult(0)
                .SetMaxResults(15)
                .List<SomeEntity>();
```

Don't know how to do this using the criteria API though.

Comment: +1. Huh that's pretty weird. I thought the answer would be part of the HQL "tunneled" string. Interesting.

Comment: This answer is actually a hybrid of HQL and the criteria API

Comment: yea..it's essentially the same as criteria...just replace with `CreateCriteria<SomeEntity>()`

Comment: any idea how to order the results before selecting the top 15?

Comment: sure - `session.CreateQuery("from SomeEntity s order by s.SomeProperty").SetFirst(....)`

Answer (score 10):

Criteria API Method:

```
ICriteria criteria = DaoSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(T));
criteria.SetFirstResult(StartIndex);
criteria.SetMaxResults(MaximumObjects);
return criteria.List<T>();
```

Comment: MaximumObjects is just an integer variable to tell SetMaxResults how many objects to return. In your case, you could hard code 15 instead, i.e. criteria.SetMaxResults(15);

Comment: Haha... so in other words it is identical to CreateQuery() after the instance is created.

Comment: You can chain all of those ICriteria method calls fluently, would make it more readable.

Answer (score 4):

From NHibernate 3.2 you could use `SKIP n / TAKE n` in hql at the end of the query. It could be very helpful in subqueries where you can not use `SetMaxResults`.

For example:

```
select l, (select u from User u where u.Location = l order by u.Date asc take 1) 
from Location l
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, here is how to do it with the `QueryOver` API introduced in NHibernate 3.0:

```
var top15 = session.QueryOver<SomeEntity>().Take(15).List();
```

Throw in a `.Skip(someInt)` if you need to define a start index, e.g. for paging.

Answer (score -2):

mookid8000 is giving false information.

there is no way of setting SQL TOP N with HQL :(

it always downloads all of the table to .NET and the takes the TOP, wich is just plain stupid!

Comment: Worked just like it was advertised. Information is not false.

Comment: I was just testing and filtering is not  happening on.Net end.