# nhibernate, Retrieve the latest row in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

A user can have many addresses, but I want to retrieve the latest entry for the user.

In sql I would do:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM UserAddress
WHERE userID = @userID
```

How can I create a criteria query with the same logic?

Is there a TOP functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have some timestamp column (eg. InsertedAt):

```
    User user = ...;
    var crit = DetachedCriteria.For<UserAddress>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("User", user))
        .AddOrder(Order.Desc("InsertedAt"))
        .SetMaxResults(1);
```

Comment: woudl this be ok?  .SetMaxResults(1).UniqueResult<UserAddress>(); ?

Comment: Yes. There were only one row :)

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555045/nhibernate-hqls-equivalent-to-t-sqls-top-keyword) has answers to how to do this, but you shouldn't always depend on `TOP` for getting the latest entry! (assuming chronological order)

Use a time/index column to get the latest entry based on a timestamp value value.

Answer (score 1):

Since the ordering of the contents of a table are subject to movement (reindexing etc), I'd suggest that you have a time stamp of some description to indicate which is the latest. Then get the first ordered by that field.